# Pasar un parámetro con @PathParam de REST desde cliente JAVA

Tags: java, webservice, rest, rutas, restful

Estoy intentando pasar un int desde un cliente Java a un WebService Rest.
He visto que se puede utilizar @PathParam para pasar un parámetro por ello he puesto esto en el WebService.

```
@GET
@Path("/tipusMoviment/{moviment}")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public int tipusMoviment(@PathParam("moviment") int moviment) {
int result = 99; //si falla el if

if (moviment == 1) {
  result = 5;
}else{
  result = 3;
}

return result;     
}
```

Ahora en el cliente tengo lo siguiente:

```
public class NewJerseyClient {

private WebTarget webTarget;
private Client client;
private static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8080/ProyectoREST1/webresources";

public NewJerseyClient() {
    client = javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder.newClient();
    webTarget = client.target(BASE_URI).path("generic");
}

public <T> T tipusMoviment(Class<T> responseType, String moviment) throws ClientErrorException {
    return webTarget.path(java.text.MessageFormat.format("tipusMoviment/{0}", new Object[]{moviment})).request().post(null, responseType);
}

public void close() {
    client.close();
}    
}
```

Y en el main

```
public class ProyectoCliente7 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    NewJerseyClient ws = new NewJerseyClient();
    System.out.println(ws.tipusMoviment(2));
} 
}
```

No se que estoy haciendo mal o cual es el problema, soy nuevo en REST y agradecería un poco de ayuda porque por mas que busco en internet no paro de encontrar cosas que no funcionan o no entiendo.

Me han dicho que usando el ws.tipusMoviment(2) tiene que funcionar pero sin embargo en internet encuentro cosas como esta:

```
Client client = Client.create();

    WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/your-app/rest/data/post");

    String input = "{\"message\":\"Hello\"}";

    ClientResponse response = webResource.type("application/json")
       .post(ClientResponse.class, input);

    if (response.getStatus() != 201) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
             + response.getStatus());
    }
```

Muchas gracias por vuestro tiempo.

Comment: Y el error cuál es??

Comment: @E.Betanzos que no se como pasar un numero desde el cliente de Java hacia el WebService Rest utilizando la funcion tipusMoviment(2).

Comment: Eso me quedó claro, pero que excepción se lanza al ejecutar `tipusMoviment()`

Comment: @E.Betanzos me dice en el main el IDE (NetBeans)
 System.out.println(tipusMoviment(2)), Create method tipusMoviment(int) in WebService.NewJerseyClient

Comment: @rafemo lograste resolver el problema??

Comment: @RaulCacacho por desgracia no.

Comment: @rafemo no se ve en tu codigo pero tienes estas anotaciones en el web service `@Stateless` y `@Path("/1.0")`

Comment: @RaulCacacho lo unico que he encontrado ha sido @Path("generic") en el lado del Restful

Comment: @rafemo puedes mostrar todo el código de  del RestFull

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76918/discussion-between-raul-cacacho-and-rafemo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He conseguido pasar el numero, para ello he utilizado:

Cliente

```
NewJerseyClient ws = new NewJerseyClient();
ws.tipusMoviment(int.class, 1)
```

Jersey

```
public <T> T tipusMoviment(Class<T> responseType, int moviment) throws ClientErrorException {
    WebTarget resource = webTarget;
    resource = resource.path(java.text.MessageFormat.format("tipusMoviment/{0}", new Object[]{moviment}));
    return resource.request(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).get(responseType);
}
```

WebService REST

```
@GET
@Path("/tipusMoviment/{moviment}")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public int tipusMoviment(@PathParam("moviment") int moviment) {
    int result = 0;
return result; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar cambiando la notación: `@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)`

Por : `@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`

Con eso debe funcionar.

Comment: Pero eso cambia de texto plano a json y a mi me interesa pasarlo como text_plain.

Comment: Lo más sano es pasar JSON, ya que como veo que pasaras un parámetro nombrado podría quedar tu json a enviar así:

{"moviment":1}

Y deberá funcionar sin problemas